# Looking for a way to speed up the following code

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns in my dataset that contain lists of elements stored as strings. I want to get the element which is common part of all these lists.

Some things to keep in mind:
1) Columns can contain 'NAN' value rather than list
2) If there are more than one common element, it doesn't really matter which one will be picked

I wrote the following function, which takes as an argument the data frame containing these three, relevant columns:

```py
def parse_genres(df):

    def get_genre(row):
        row_list = []
        for element in row:
            if element != 'NAN':
                y = ast.literal_eval(element)
                for genre in y:
                    if genre not in row_list:
                        row_list += genre
        unique = set(row_list)
        return list(unique)[0]

    result = df.apply(get_genre)
    return result
```

Input:

```
index   col1                  col2                                    col3
0       NAN                   NAN                                     NAN
1       ['hip hop', 'trap']   ['indie', 'trap']                       NAN
2       ['pop', 'viral pop']  ['dance pop', 'pop', 'post-teen pop']   NAN
```

Expected output:

```
index   col
0       NAN
1       'trap'
2       'pop'
```

Comment: Adding a set of sample inputs and expected output, will help.

Comment: if you use `if genre not in row_list` then you create list with unique values and you don't need `set()`. OR convert all strings to lists and then all lists to sets and do `set1 & set2 & set3` to get unique values.

Answer (score 1):

have made some optimisations. see if that helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'col1': [np.nan,['hip hop', 'trap'],['pop', 'viral pop','post-teen pop']],
    'col2': [np.nan,['indie', 'trap'],['dance pop', 'pop', 'post-teen pop']],
    'col3': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['common_words'])
for idx, rows in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    new_set = None
    valid_set_found = False
    for i in range(len(rows[1])):
        if isinstance(rows[1][i], list):
            if valid_set_found is False:
                new_set = set(rows[1][i])
                valid_set_found = True
                continue
            new_set = set(rows[1][i]) & new_set

    if new_set is None:
        result_df.loc[idx] = np.nan
    else:
        new_list = list(new_set)
        result_df.loc[idx] = [new_list]

print(df)
print(result_df)

Input :
                              col1                             col2  col3
0                              NaN                              NaN   NaN
1                  [hip hop, trap]                    [indie, trap]   NaN
2  [pop, viral pop, post-teen pop]  [dance pop, pop, post-teen pop]   NaN
Output : 
           common_words
0                   NaN
1                [trap]
2  [pop, post-teen pop]
```